# Ruby rainbows/unicorn start faye and rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn, rainbows

Is there a way i can start both faye and rails apps together in rainbows/unicorn.

Right now i'm using rainbows to start faye/private_pub app but would like to start rails also with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman?source=c)?

With foreman you can set the commands to start your app on a single file, like this

```
web: bundle exec start_app_command
faye: bundle exec start_faye_command
```

and then, just run `bundle exec foreman start` and foreman will run both rails and faye

Comment: Yes found this gem and using it to start both servers